# Rust generic function accepting integer types

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write functions that check/clear/set/toggle specific bits. I want to be able to use those functions on all integer types so i don't have to, for example, do this:

```rust
let x = 4;
(x as usize).check_bit(0);
```

and can do

```rust
let x = 4;
x.check_bit(0);
```

Regardless of whether x is i32 or i64.
I've found num_traits crate but I'm not sure if i'm using it correctly. Here is what I have so far:

```rust
use num_traits::Num;

trait BitManipulation {
    fn is_bit_set(&self, n: usize) -> bool;
    fn set_bit(&mut self, n: usize) -> Self;
    fn set_bit_in_place(&mut self, n: usize);
    fn clear_bit(&self, n: usize) -> Self;
    fn clear_bit_in_place(&mut self, n: usize);
    fn toggle_bit(&self, n: usize) -> Self;
    fn toggle_bit_in_place(&mut self, n: usize);
}

impl<T: Num> BitManipulation for T {
    fn is_bit_set(&self, n: usize) -> bool {
        (self & (1 << n).into()) != 0
    }

    fn set_bit(&mut self, n: usize) -> T {
        self | (1 << n).into()
    }

    fn set_bit_in_place(&mut self, n: usize) {
        *self |= (1 << n).into();
    }

    fn clear_bit(&self, n: usize) -> T {
        self & (!(1 << n).into())
    }

    fn clear_bit_in_place(&mut self, n: usize) {
        *self &= (!(1 << n).into());
    }

    fn toggle_bit(&self, n: usize) -> T {
        self ^ (1 << n).into()
    }

    fn toggle_bit_in_place(&mut self, n: usize) {
        *self ^= (1 << n).into()
    }
}
```

However it is not working and I get a lot of errors for example:
```no implementation for `&mut T | _```` so there must be something completly wrong with my approach.

Comment: That is indeed what you have so far. You don't seem to have a question though. Is something about it not working?

Comment: @JohnBayko Well, none of it is working and I have no idea how to make it work. Most errors seem to be some form of "no implementation for `&mut T &/^ _`" where operator is

Comment: You probably want to add further bounds like `for<'a> &'a T: std::ops::BitAnd<T>` for `&` and `Shl` for `<<`, …

Comment: Also `1` isn't of type `T`, but `T::one()` is.